# Image Reveal on mousemove using translateX with gradient

Tags: jquery, css, transform, mousemove, translate-animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window),
    $overlay = $('.example2'),
    rotation = 0,
    transOver = 0

  $window.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    transOver = (event.pageX / $window.width() * 1720) - 690;
    $overlay.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transOver + 'px)');
  });
});
```

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.stopOverflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.example3 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -3;
}
.example2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.example1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="stopOverflow">
  <img class="example1 img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/iHBQH7o.png">
  <img class="example2 img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/0sBuSLm.png">
  <img class="example3 img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/9T7zUhd.png">
</div>
```

So I have 3 images(if there is a better way to handle this I am all ears). The effect I need is for a shower to look like it is turning on. I am currently using 3 layers. The top layer is just the shower head. The middle layer is the image with a gradient, and the bottom is the water. The images are all the same size and set to be responsive.

The issue is that the image with the gradient moves either too little or too much to the left or right on different resolutions. Which I am sure is because of values I'm using. I just need it to be consistent across multiple sized monitors. Mobile is obviously not an issue. Fiddle is posted below

https://jsfiddle.net/5v0b7tL8/2/

Comment: Okay so I answered my own question. I changed the translateX to use % instead of px. That finally got it to work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by looking at this codepen

http://blog.mediamonkfish.com/animating-css3-gradients-on-mouse-move/

I still used an image, but changing the script to this

```
$window.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    transOver = (event.pageX / $window.width() * 100);
    $overlay.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transOver + '%)');
  });
```

That set it to use the % of the screen which made it consistent. At least I think that is what it did versus using a set pixel amount.